# Configuring Vendor specific client API as an endpoint in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have vendor provided product which is running over Weblogic, its an EJB.
Vendor has also provided the Client API to communicate with the EJB and send various request to interact with EJB.

Client API is packaged in jar.

TO communicate we need to first get the factory using the client API. then using factory we have to get connection, using connection we can communicate to EJB hosted over server.

plz help and provide some suggestion how to load this jar file and how to configure the end point in camel.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you interact with the EJB?
Camel has a [camel-ejb](http://camel.apache.org/ejb) component, you can use it as the bean object by setting up the context information.

If you just want to call the EJB object with the client API, you can put the calling logic into a [Processor](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) implementation, and put the processor into the camel route.